# How i can send model data in new field on template

Tags: python, django

> **How i can do custom fields for my Model and send it to tempalte?**

supp - new property for Dish model. If i do print `(i.dish.supp)` i will see Supplement objects But in template i don't have it... how i can get it in template.

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.request.user

    try:
        if user.is_authenticated():
            userorders = UserOrder.objects.filter(user_id=user.id,
                                                  is_closed=0)
        else:
            user_hash = self.request.session.get('user_hash')
            userorders = UserOrder.objects.filter(user_hash=user_hash,
                                                  is_closed=0)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        context['data_dish'] = []
        return context

    try:
        context['address'] = UserAddress.objects.get(
            user_id=user.id,
            is_main=1)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        context['address'] = False

    for order in userorders:
        summ = order.order_summ = order.userorder.filter(
            order_id=order.id).aggregate(Sum('price'))
        for i in order.userorder.all():
            sum = Supplement.objects.filter(
                id__in=eval(i.supplements)).aggregate(
                s=Sum('price'))

            i.dish.supp = Supplement.objects.filter(
                id__in=eval(i.supplements)).values('name')

    context['orders'] = userorders
return context
```

in tempklate

......

```
{% for order in orders.all %}

    <div class="main_order_{{  order.shop.id }} cart" >

        <div class="cart-title">
            <a href="/shop/{{ order.shop.id }}/">{{ order.shop.name }}</a>
            {% for shop, msg in shop_msg %}{% if shop == order.shop %}{{ msg|safe|escape }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
        </div>

        {% for i in order.userorder.all %}
            <div class="cart-item">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <img src="{% static 'img/roll.png' %}" alt="" width="90">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h5>{{ i.dish.name }}</h5>
                        <span>Салат, {{ i.dish.weight }} г.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

but

```
{{ i.dish.supp }}
```

is empty

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for context, which is in the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Comment: yea i send it to context['orders'] = userorders and try pars it to template? but don't have `supp`

Comment: Can you add the relevant code from your view and template here then?

Comment: Yeag sure. done please see that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pasted all of the code from your `get_context_data()` method, the issue is that you aren't returning the context (look at the very last line), nor are you adding `i.dish.supp` to the context (be careful with those periods, I changed them to underscores here):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CartView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.request.user

    try:
        if user.is_authenticated():
            userorders = UserOrder.objects.filter(user_id=user.id,
                                                  is_closed=0)
        else:
            user_hash = self.request.session.get('user_hash')
            userorders = UserOrder.objects.filter(user_hash=user_hash,
                                                  is_closed=0)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        context['data_dish'] = []
        return context

    try:
        context['address'] = UserAddress.objects.get(
            user_id=user.id,
            is_main=1)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        context['address'] = False

    for order in userorders:
        summ = order.order_summ = order.userorder.filter(
            order_id=order.id).aggregate(Sum('price'))
        for i in order.userorder.all():
            sum = Supplement.objects.filter(
                id__in=i.supplements).aggregate(
                s=Sum('price'))

            i.dish.supp = Supplement.objects.filter(
                id__in=i.supplements).values('name')

            context['i_dish_supp'] = i.dish.supp

    context['orders'] = userorders
    # And now we provide the context
    return context
```

Also, don't use `eval()`  for id_in - it's not necessary. Keep in mind that in the code I added, there will only be one `i_dish_supp`. It looks like you want one for each order, but I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

You should take a look at [ccbv.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.base/ContextMixin/) it provides a great way to see the class based views, and all of their methods.

Comment: Updated with something else I noticed

Comment: context['i_dish_supp'] = i.dish.supp so how i can make it in template?

Comment: it does not solve my problem but simply records the result of the last iteration, iteration-cascade ... on a different number of objects

Answer (score 0):

i do next, in my model

```
@property
def get_supplements(self):
    return Supplement.objects.filter(id__in=eval(self.supplements))
```

in template

```
       {% for supp in i.get_supplements %}
           <span>{{ supp.name }}</span>
      {% endfor %}
```